# Programming Language Reference: String Replacement

Tags: string, reference, replace

I am seeing if it's worthwhile creating a reference showing how to do common things in multiple programming languages.

Please list below the command that you would use to achieve the following in your chosen programming language:

String Replacement

examples:

PHP:

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

Objective-C:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Comment: Who's the audience for this kind of information?

Comment: I do think it would be great to have a sort of rosetta stone for common tasks in multiple languages, but that would be a blog post, not a question.

Comment: S.Lott: I can't be the only one after information like this?

Earwicker, Dave: Wiki - good idea. Wikipedia does have a section:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

Thanks for the vote down whoever it was. Have a nice day.

Comment: This should be somewhere more specialized, where someone can choose the language and get a list of the common tasks. As a question or even blog post, it's not easy to access.

Comment: As Dave points out, there probably is interest in this topic, it just doesn't fit the SO model very well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. As I said in the question I am seeing if it is worthwhile right now. I love SO and thought I might get some reasonable opinion on the idea. Happy to move the discussion elsewhere once I am satisfied.

Comment: http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages.html#Strng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java:

```
String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct entry as it was the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TSQL

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```